# Is the following series converging $\sum_{n=2}\dfrac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the following series converging $\sum_{n=2}\dfrac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$

I am not able to compare this with anything, can some show the way

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Our denominator is $\exp((\ln\ln n)(\ln n))$, which is $n^{\ln\ln n}$. Now think $p$-series and Comparison.

**Remark:** When we meet $a^b$, the fact that it is equal to $\exp((\ln a)(b))$ is frequently useful.

Comment: Ok thinking like $p$- series we see that $ln ln n >1$ so can we conclude directly that the series diverges? Why we need comparison?

Comment: Basically that's it, though early on $\ln\ln n\lt 1$. The term $p$-series is reserved for series $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$ where $p$ is **constant** so ours is not a $p$-series, but after a while the $n$-th term is smaller than $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and we do comparison.

Comment: Hmmm that's right.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
L'Hospitals rule gives us$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\ln n}{n}=0.$$ Therefore $$2\le\ln n\le n$$ for sufficiently large $n$ values. This implies $$\dfrac{1}{\ln n^{\ln n}}\le\dfrac{1}{n^2}.$$ I'm sure you can continue from here.

Comment: I don't see how you got your last inequality from the preceding one.  (Doesn't this imply that $n\ln 2\le (\ln n)(\ln(\ln n))$ for n large?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure this works, though.  For example, $1/3\le1/2$, but $(\frac{1}{3})^2>(\frac{1}{2})^4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n\ge e^{(e^2)}$, then $\ln n\ge e^2\implies \ln(\ln n)\ge 2\implies$

$(\ln n)(\ln(\ln n))\ge 2 \ln n\implies \ln[(\ln n)^{\ln n}]\ge\ln(n^2)\implies(\ln n)^{\ln n}\ge n^2\implies \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}\le\frac{1}{n^2}$,

so the series converges by the Comparison Test with $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.